# Creating a Virtual Interactive Object with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web page where I have 5 buttons which when clicked, make the object respond. Now, I just used the toggle class option but I am sure there is a better way since I am having difficulty getting the bugs worked out.

Issues:

- When you go through and press multiple buttons, sometimes it doesn't remove the current class its on. For instance, tell the object to go to sleep then press another button, it won't work unless you click the button twice.
- How do you set a timeout function to make the object go back to normal after a certain amount of time?

HTML:

```
<div id="cat" class="catNormal"></div>
<div class="container">
<ul class="commands">
    <li><input type="button" value="Look left, kitty!" id="catLeft"></li>
    <li><input type="button" value="Look right, kitty!" id="catRight"></li>
    <li><input type="button" value="Pet kitty!" id="catPurr"></li>
    <li><input type="button" value="Go to sleep kitty!" id="catSleep"></li>
    <li><input type="button" value="Good kitty!" id="catWag"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Set Kitty as object
var myKitty= {
getKitty: document.getElementById("#cat"), 
}


// Make Kitty look left
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catLeft").click(function() {
        $(".catNormal").toggleClass("catLeft");
    });
});

// Make Kitty look right
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catRight").click(function() {
        $(".catNormal").toggleClass("catRight");
    });
});

// Pet the kitty
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catPurr").click(function() {
        $(".catNormal").toggleClass("catPurr");
    });
});

// Make Kitty sleep
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catSleep").click(function() {
        $(".catNormal").toggleClass("catSleep");
    });
});

// Make Kitty wag tail
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#catWag").click(function() {
        $(".catNormal").toggleClass("catWag");
    });
});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var interval = null,
        timeout = 1000;

    var normalClass = 'catNormal';
    var catButtons = ['catLeft', 'catRight', 'catPurr', 'catSleep', 'catWag'];
    var catObj = $('#cat');

    function resetTheCat() {
        catObj.attr('class', normalClass);
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < catButtons.length; i++) {
        $("#" + catButtons[i]).click((function (className) {
            return function() {
                resetTheCat();
                catObj.toggleClass(className);

                interval = setInterval(function() {
                    resetTheCat()
                }, timeout);
            }
        })(catButtons[i]));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but that did not work. When the button is clicked, the object disappears entirely.

Comment: Oh, I see what I was doing wrong! Thank you, the way you did it makes much more sense.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please **explain** the problem and your solution. This will be a lot more helpful than simply posting a wall of code.

Comment: @FelixKling will do next time, thank you. For now user3538063 has a pretty detailed explanation of what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/digevu/3/)**

```
var $cat = $('#cat');

$('.commands :button').click(function() {

   $cat.removeClass().addClass(this.id); // Same class as the clicked ID btn.
   setTimeout(function(){                // Reset to normal after 1000ms.
       $cat.removeClass().addClass('catNormal');
   }, 1000);

});
```

The good part about the above is that you already assigned alike `ID` as the needed mood `classes`, so to target a desired class `this.id` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you click a button, your code toggles a class. These classes are overriding one another, and toggleclass places them in alphabetical order. So this means the fifth one will always override the preceding ones, the fourth one will always override the previous three but not the fifth etc, so it creates a set of rules, not bugs.

Essentially, you're giving your cat multiple behaviors by adding multiple classes. If you wish to have it only perform one at a time, I'd recommend removing all classes and adding only the one you push. Also, it might be more efficient to use a different code structure:

```
$(document).on({
click: function (event, ui) {
    var element = $(event.target);
    var element_id = element.attr('id');
    if (element.attr('type') == 'input'){
        $("#cat").removeClass(); // removeclass with no parameters removes all classes...
        $("#cat").addClass("catNormal"); // Recommend removing this class altogether and simply applying the css to the ID....
        $("#cat").addClass(element_id); // Since your button IDs match your classes you wish to add, we can get away with this here.
    }
   }
});
```

The above code is all you'll need. It is a click handler, and handles any "input" item events that occur on the page. It fetches the item's ID, strips the "#cat" element of all it's classes, and re-adds the "catNormal" class plus the button's ID as a class. You should remove the "catNormal" class, however, and simply apply the css to the ID instead if that is to be your default behavior.